# How to create index on a path in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph that has nodes and relationships that are modeled as follows:

```
(:person) - [:property] -> (:property) <- [:instance] - (:syntax)
```

For example:

```
(p:person {id: 12345}) - [:property] -> (:property {value: 'adam@gmail.com', type: 'personal'}) <- [:instance] - (:syntax {name: 'email', type: 'complex', multivalued: true, subattributes: ['value', 'type']})
```

I want to create an index on email values to speed up the following type of search:

```
MATCH (p:person) - [:property] -> (prop:property {value: 'adam@gmail.com'}) <- [:instance] - (s:syntax {name: 'email'}) RETURN p
```

Does CQL support defining indexes on paths ?

I think I need something like

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 FOR (:syntax {name: 'email'}) - [:instance] -> (p:property) ON p.value
```

Comment: Indexes are based on nodes or relationship properties. What you need is an index on the email property of the `property` nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Cypher does not support creating indexes on paths directly. However, you can create an index on the property of a specific node label, which can help improve the performance of your queries.

You can create an index on the `value` property of the `property` node label:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 FOR (p:property) ON (p.value)
```

This index will help speed up the query you provided, the index on the `value` property of the `property` node will be used to find matching nodes more efficiently.

```
MATCH (p:person) - [:property] -> (prop:property {value: 'adam@gmail.com'}) <- [:instance] - (s:syntax {name: 'email'}) RETURN p
```